# AWS Cognito Login & Signup using google

Tags: amazon-web-services, oauth-2.0, amazon-cognito, google-signin

Currently I have Signin and Signup functionality using username and password via AWS SDK and https://www.npmjs.com/package/amazon-cognito-identity-js

As the next step I want to enable social login as well like google and I have created client and enabled google as well and its working fine using hosted UI.

I want to integrate it programmatically. How can I do that, I have no idea for next step?

Answer (score 0):

The social login feature is supported through OAuth2.0+OIDC. Use the [amplify auth package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@aws-amplify/auth) or any OIDC client (such as [AppAuth](https://appauth.io/)) to handle the OAuth flow. You can pass an additional query string parameter `identity_provider` on the [authorization URI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/authorization-endpoint.html) to redirect the user to your IDP so they won't be presented with the IDP selection screen.